# Can you add a different CNAME record than the subdomain prefix that you use to customise the URL of a Google Site

Tags: url, cname, google-sites-2016

I customised my Google Sites (Google Workplace) url from "sites.google.com/domain.com/sitename" to "www.domain.com". As a subdomain prefix I used www.  In order to make the site work, I need to insert a CNAME record with hostname "www" and content "ghs.googlehosted.com".

Unfortunately my webhosting doens't allow "www" as a CNAME name.

Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what webhosting has to do with it, I think you meant your domain registrar.

You can do the following if your domain registrar does not allow you to create a CNAME record pointing to the www subdomain:

1. Create an account with [Cloudflare](https://dash.cloudflare.com/sign-up). It's free.
2. Add your domain to your Cloudflare account.
3. Change NS servers at your domain registrar to NS servers that are assigned to your Cloudflare account.
4. Create all necessary records, including the CNAME record you need in Cloudflare.

As a bonus, if your domain isn't the primary one, you will be able to implement a [small hack](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/redirect-example-com-to-www-example-com/78348) that allows you to redirect from your naked domain to its www version (if the domain is the primary one, then you can do this in the [console](https://admin.google.com/ac/domains/manage)).